# how to integrate gerrit with bugzilla for closing bug form git command?

Tags: git, gerrit, bugzilla

I am using `gerrit(git)` for `VCS` and bugzilla for bug tracking.

i am trying to integrate bugzilla with git. so developer can close bug from git using this command :

```
git commit -m "close #154"
```

already tried `VCS` extension for bugzilla but its not working. Please help.

vcs url `http://code.google.com/p/bugzilla-vcs/`

Comment: I would combine [gerrit hooks](https://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.2/config-hooks.html) with [bugzilla CLI](https://github.com/williamh/pybugz)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check the [its-bugzilla](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/its-bugzilla/) plugin for Gerrit. See [its features](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/its-bugzilla/+/26b30979fdac2e87de1180fd7bbe256e5cc07942/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md).

If this does not fulfill your needs, you should use [gerrit-hooks](http://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html) to perform certain actions (i.e. contacting your Bugzilla API), as @HiB suggested.

However, it will be impossible to close issue on `git commit` command with Gerrit hooks. If you meant the action of pushing the commit to Gerrit (`git push` command), then you'd be intrested in [patchset-created](http://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html#_patchset_created) hook.

IMHO, making a `close #154` commit only in order to do some magic actions automatically is not the best workflow I can imagine. I would prefer to create a `[#154] Fix issue` commit and close Bugzilla item as soon as the commit has been reviewed and merged. For this attitude you should look at [change-merged](http://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html#_change_merged) gerrit hook to read issue number from merged commit message and contact Bugzilla.